# batch file name renumber

Tags: file, batch-file

I have a batch file that creates a `.txt` file with Date as name, e.g. `11-09-2018.txt`.

There is a new requirement came is to append `-n` number every time it runs.

Like:
 - the 1st run of batch file will create the file with name `11-09-2018-1.txt`, 
 - the 2nd run will create `11-09-2018-2.txt`, 
 - the 3rd run will create `11-09-2018-3.txt`.

Below is my current code for creating batch file with Date in name :

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do set mydate=%%i
set mydate=%mydate:/=-%
set filename=%mydate%.txt
```

Then using `%filename%` where ever I want.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Append a counter to the name, if a file with that name already exists - increase the counter.

Comment: Thanks @LotPings
can you please share piece of code for counter increment. i am new to batch files so don't know much coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Append a counter to the name, if a file with that name already exists - increase the counter.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2" %%i in ('date /t') do set "mydate=%%i"
set "mydate=%mydate:/=-%"
set "cnt=1"
:loop
set "filename=%mydate%-%cnt%.txt"
if exist "%filename%" (set /a "cnt+=1" & goto :loop)
```

Comment: tried, its creating  name_1.txt but not adding any more txt files but just appending the output from next run in the same file. It means "filename" is not changing every time
can you tell me where specifically it checks the "if exist "%filename%", which path. also is it possible to give path/dir here like "if exist "C:/%filename%"

Comment: "if exist "C:/%filename%" worked for me
thanks alot @LotPings